# Rails form select with NULL (no choice) support

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

How can I add a NULL option to my form select? I have a table:

```
categories
id
category_id
name
```

If I'm creating a new category, I want to be able to select the `NO_CATEGORY` option (NULL value and id).

My view code:

```
<%= f.collection_select :supercategory_id, Category.all, :id , :name %>
```

Also, it is a good idea? Isn't it better to have some predefined ROOT category in the database? Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
<%= f.collection_select :supercategory_id, Category.all, :id , :name, :include_blank => true %>
```

Its ok to have null.  Just have your model logic know that it should create a new category and assign it rather than mass assign from the select.  Might be something that happens in a before_validation method

Comment: thank yout it works :-) (i also forgot change supercategory_id to category_id too)